# Confused when using the completableFuture for reading the file

Tags: java, future

I tried to estimate the performance between async and sync.
I wrote some easy async code which is reading the file and printing the result.
I divided them into two parts, one is reading the file and the other is printing the result.

below is my whole code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class AsyncExample {

  private static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AsyncExample asyncExample = new AsyncExample();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    ExecutorService dbExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32);

    ClassLoader classLoader = AsyncExample.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(
            "data_id.json");

    Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();

    BlockingQueue<String> lineQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    CompletableFuture<Void> readFileFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          lineQueue.offer(line);
          counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }, executor);

    CompletableFuture<Void> writeToDbFuture1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      while (true) {
        String line = lineQueue.poll();
        if (line != null) {
          CompletableFuture<Void> dbTask = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            asyncExample.doTask(line);
          }, dbExecutor);

          dbTask.thenAccept(result -> {
            System.out.println("Task is done");
          });
        } else if (readFileFuture.isDone()) {
          if (counter.get()==0) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }, dbExecutor);

    try {
      readFileFuture.get();
      writeToDbFuture1.get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      executor.shutdown();
      dbExecutor.shutdown();
      Long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - ts;
      System.out.println("time : " + end);
    }
  }

  private void doTask(String line) {
    try {
      System.out.println(line);
      Thread.sleep(500);
      counter.decrementAndGet();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

The `data_is.json` looks as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

The program finished within 1 seconds because the task is parallel.

To enhance my code, I think that below code is little bit strange to me because it has nested completable future.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> writeToDbFuture1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      while (true) {
        String line = lineQueue.poll();
        if (line != null) {
          CompletableFuture<Void> dbTask = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            asyncExample.doTask(line);
          }, dbExecutor);

          dbTask.thenAccept(result -> {
            System.out.println("Task is done");
          });
        } else if (readFileFuture.isDone()) {
          if (counter.get()==0) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }, dbExecutor);
```

So I changed it into as below one.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> writeToDbFuture2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
  while (true) {
    String line = lineQueue.poll();
    if (line != null) {
      asyncExample.doTask(line);
    } else if (readFileFuture.isDone()) {
      if (counter.get() == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}, dbExecutor);
```

I removed the nested and expected the result is same but it didn't.

It took about 7 secs which is similar to the sync one.

From this observation, I have the following questions.

1. Why the second one cannot be run as parallel?
2. the first code is no problem in programmatic way?